# How to change the active branch on Git repository of IBM DevOps Service?

Tags: git, gitlab, ibm-cloud, devops

I'm using Git repository of IBM DevOps Service.
In the overview screen, files of master branch are always shown though I works mainly on develop branch. The develop branch is listed in the list box I know, but I'd like to get files on develop branch immediately.
Also I know, in the case of normal GitLab, I can set default branch in setting screen. But I cannot find similar setting on IBM DevOps Service.

Do you know how to change the active branch on Git repository of IBM DevOps Service?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your situation correctly, with DevOps Services you can check out the develop branch instead of switching to it each time. If you check out the branch, it stays as your active branch, even if you shut down.

To check out a branch:

1. From the overview page of your app, click **EDIT CODE**.
2. Click **Git Repository**. [Git Repository button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lM8s.png)
3. In the Reference menu, find your branch and click the Checkout button. [Checkout button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uheeF.png)

I hope that helps.